# Statistical test for CATA (check-all-that-apply - multiple response) question

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, proportion, multiple-response

A survey question asks to tick all options that are relevant to the users (Check all that apply). Respondents are given 6 options and they can tick as many as they want.
I want to determine which are the top 3 options.
I can sort the options by frequency (see data below), but that does not tell me whether e.g. the third most frequent option is significantly more frequent than the fourth.
I want to test whether the difference in frequency is statistically significant between the 6 options and compare the different options (post hoc).

My best option is to calculate the confidence interval around each frequency and compare those, but I wonder whether there is a more rigorous test.

This is the data (I sorted it by descending frequency)

**sample size n=150**

- **Feature Frequency**
- qualifications 82%
- work_experience 75%
- case studies 53%
- personal_brand 49%
- awards 42%
- career_goal 12%

Comment: Use Cochran's Q test with subsequent multiple comparisons. For your situation, I may recommend not all pairwise comparisons but the stepwise stepdown procedure which isolates subsets of items between which the difference is statistically most significant. Also to note, the Q test is just the Friedman test in case of binary data (your data are 6 binary variables).

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.